# Selection max items of specific aliases with XSLT and Umbraco

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, umbraco

I have a small challenge with some XSLT and Umbraco.

It is a "function" to output job adverts.

I have to select a maximum of 3 nodes (job adverts) out X nodes and with those 3 nodes I want to select two of X type and one of Y type.

I have a property alias called `jobAdType` and I want to select two nodes that have `jobAdType= Vikar` and one node that have `jobAdType= Fast job`. Ad type is selected from a drop-down in Umbraco.

The XML of an adverts is:

```
<FrontPageAd id="1379" parentID="1246" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="0" createDate="2014-11-07T11:40:14" updateDate="2014-11-12T09:09:55" nodeName="Annonce 1" urlName="annonce-1" path="-1,1058,1246,1379" isDoc="" nodeType="1245" creatorName="ITSecurity" writerName="ITSecurity" writerID="0" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="FrontPageAd">
  <adHeader>Headr</adHeader>
  <adBodyText>jkdjdk</adBodyText>
  <adCompany>Test firma</adCompany>
  <adPosition>Test stilling</adPosition>
  <adCompanyLogo>
   <MultiNodePicker type="media">
     <nodeId>1317</nodeId>
   </MultiNodePicker>
  </adCompanyLogo>
  <jobAdType>Vikar</jobAdType>
</FrontPageAd>
```

The current XSLT is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="header" select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Frontpage.Content.JobAdsHeader')" />

<xsl:if test="$adCount &gt; 0">

    <div class="jobAdsContainer">

        <strong class="header uc"><xsl:value-of select="$header" /></strong>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="adslider">

                <ul class="noList adList slideList">

                    <xsl:for-each select="$adIds [position() &lt; 4]">

                        <xsl:variable name="adItem" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(.)" />

                        <xsl:call-template name="JobTypeItem">                      
                            <xsl:with-param name="item" select="$adItem" />
                        </xsl:call-template>

                    </xsl:for-each>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</xsl:if>
```

```
<xsl:variable name="companyLabel" select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Frontpage.AdList.Company')" />
<xsl:variable name="positionLabel" select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Frontpage.AdList.Position')" />
<xsl:variable name="contactPersonLabel" select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('Frontpage.AdList.ContactPerson')" />

<xsl:variable name="adType" select="$item/jobAdType" />
<xsl:variable name="adTitle" select="$item/@nodeName" />
<xsl:variable name="adHeader" select="$item/adHeader" />
<xsl:variable name="adBodyText" select="$item/adBodyText" />
<xsl:variable name="adCompany" select="$item/adCompany" />
<xsl:variable name="adPosition" select="$item/adPosition" />
<xsl:variable name="adLogo" select="$item/adCompanyLogo/descendant::nodeId" />

<li>

    <xsl:if test="$adLogo != ''">

        <div class="table">

            <div class="adImage">                                                       
                <xsl:variable name="image" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($adLogo, 0)" />

                    <img src="{Eksponent.CropUp:Url($image/umbracoFile, '175x-M')}" />          
            </div>

        </div>

    </xsl:if>

    <span class="header uc"><xsl:value-of select="$adHeader" /></span>                                      
    <span class="company"><strong><xsl:value-of select="$companyLabel" />:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $adCompany)" /></span>
    <span class="position"><strong><xsl:value-of select="$positionLabel" />:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $adPosition)" /></span> 

    <span class="description">
        <xsl:value-of select="$adBodyText" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </span>

</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "apply-templates" instead of this for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$adIds [position() &lt; 4]">
<!-- Is this .net call necessary? Is . another node other then the current one? -->
<xsl:variable name="adItem" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(.)" />
<xsl:call-template name="JobTypeItem">                      
<xsl:with-param name="item" select="$adItem" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then limit the nodes in the select statement:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="FrontPageAd[position() &lt; 3][string(./jobAdType) = 'Vikar']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="FrontPageAd[position() &lt; 2][string(./jobAdType) = 'Fast job']"/>
```

Then add a template that matches FrontPageAd

```
<xsl:template match="FrontPageAd">
<!-- add code goes here. -->
</xsl:template>
```